# Vue dynamic background image inline component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component

I'm building a banner with Vue that needs to have a dynamic background, however, it doesn't seem to be working. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried a few other ways and it works if I do an image tag something like

```
<img :src="require(`@/assets/images/${backgroundImage}`)" />
```

But obviously this needs to be an inline background image.

Code:

component

```
<template>
  <div
    class="w-full h-64 bg-auto bg-no-repeat bg-center lg:bg-cover relative"
    :style="{ backgroundImage: url(require('@/assets/images/' + backgroundImage))}"
  >
    <div class="w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-white px-6">
      <div class="hero-text rounded text-center py-8 px-12">
        <p class="text-base lg:text-md uppercase font-medium">{{ smallLeadingText }}</p>
        <h1 class="text-xl md:text-3xl lg:text-5xl uppercase font-bold">{{ mainText }}</h1>
        <p class="text-base lg:text-md">{{ subText }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "PageHero",
  props: {
    backgroundImage: String,
    smallLeadingText: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    },
    mainText: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    subText: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

View

```
<PageHero
  backgroundImage="mc-background.png "
  smallLeadingText="Powerful, secure &amp; affordable"
  mainText="Minecraft hosting"
  subText="Plans suitable for all budgets"
/>
```

Comment: Would you be able to give an example @Phil? If you don't mind

Comment: So I tried your code @Phil but it removes the code https://gyazo.com/09f006c0bdef02156051924a9f30037b if I remove the `:style` the code shows without the background

Comment: I may have messed something up in the comment so I've moved it to an answer below. I'd definitely preference using computed properties instead of doing everything inline

Comment: FYI, I've always found it works best to use kebab-cased attribute names when passing props, ie `background-image="mc-background.png"`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case and https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Prop-name-casing-strongly-recommended

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you've just got some syntax errors in your `style` attribute around string quoting. Try

```html
<div :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${require('@/assets/images/' + backgroundImage)})` }">
```

---

Might be easier to create some computed properties to resolve everything though

```js
computed: {
  bgImage () {
    return require('@/assets/images/' + this.backgroundImage)
  },
  inlineStyle () {
    return {
      backgroundImage: `url(${this.bgImage})` 
    }
  }
}
```

and

```html
<div :style="inlineStyle">
```

Demo ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-sky-ehn9r

Comment: So I tried your code but it removes the code gyazo.com/09f006c0bdef02156051924a9f30037b if I remove the :style the code shows without the background even with the computed route.

Comment: Same issue for both examples just shows the component as commented `<--->` and doesn't actually show with the `style` bind.

Comment: @debugabug works fine for me. I've added a demo link

Comment: Hey, here is a small video of what is happening, not sure why as everything is correct given the example link. https://i.gyazo.com/91d584adb32ef0f148e1a13397b3c1d6.mp4

Comment: @debugabug There's three errors in your browser console. What are they?

Comment: Here you go @phil https://gyazo.com/3b275ca7bb2ea9f3e0bf24364fef4c5a

Answer (score 0):

**Point 1: Syntax**

While the other solution does not work for me, this does:

```
<div :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${'src/assets/images/' + backgroundImage})`}"></div>
```

Of course, you need the height property to display the image.

This solution does not include "require", which will save you the error of "require" not defined.

**Point 2: Path**

You can go to the browser's console, Network tab, and check if the image actually gets loaded. The path may be incorrect, for example:

```
'../assets/images/'
```

and

```
'@/assets/images/'
```

did not work for me, but this:

```
'src/assets/images'
```

and this:

```
src/images
```

did, depending on the project. I have not looked into why 'assets' was skipped for some projects and not others, but for now you can try these options.