# Vue.js won't load background images

Tags: html, css, vue.js

*Using Vue CLI*

Hi, I'm currently updgrading a website with vue.js and everything works fine except for background images.

Inside one of the views, I have this code:

```
<div v-for="(member, i) in team" :style="{'background-image': `linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--end-opacity)) 50%),url(${require(getStyle(i))})`}" :key="i">
  <h2>{{member.name}}</h2>
  <p class="member-desc">{{text.about.members[i]}}</p>
</div>
```

I get background image url from a json file (image is stored in assets folder) and it looks like this : '@/assets/images/nicolas.jpg'.
The "getStyle" function defined in methods looks like this :

```
getStyle (index) {
   return this.team[index].image
}
```

The problem is the website doesn't show images and returns *GET http://localhost:8080/@/assets/images/nicolas.jpg* error.

If I change urls to images stored on the web it works, but not locally. Is there any reason why?

Comment: Hey, check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60859696/2092969

Comment: @cainelli Thanks, but I already saw this and so the whole url is stored in the json file, not just a parameter. So I tried the answers from this question but they don't solve the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue dynamic background image inline component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859602/vue-dynamic-background-image-inline-component)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to tweak the image url from the json file to:

`src/assets/images/nicolas.jpg`

I had the same problem where

```
../assets/images/
```

and

```
@/assets/images/
```

did not work, but specifying 'src' did. Also, in the inline html, instead of calling getStyle(index), how about putting the image url inline dynamically? Say, instead of

```
url(${require(getStyle(i))})
```

how about:

```
url(${ 'src/assets/images/' + member.image})
```

Answer (score 0):

> http://localhost:8080/@/assets/images/nicolas.jpg

Your builder does not convert the "@" alias.  Set up an alias.

Comment: Thanks ! I searched for it and I have no clue how to do that. Is there a tutorial or stuff?

Comment: @SamuelTandonnet Each builder has his own way of setting up an alias